App shows blank screen when continuously used
I am testing a kiosk Android application. This is a food-ordering kiosk application. The device's RAM is 8GB.
The flow of the application is:
The user comes to the app. At first, the banner video is playing. The video duration is variable. It can vary between 4-15 seconds. The user clicks the app to go inside, add items to the cart, and place the order. After the order is complete; it again redirects to the banner video screen.
Problem:
This process will keep happening all the day. The kiosk is never off. After 3-4 days when it's on its video gets paused; a blank screen shows and nothing happens. However, when the app is closed and reopened, it starts again.
I have tried all the ways to find out why the screen goes blank and the video doesn't play. I have two kiosk machines with Android 9 and Android 13. Both have the same issue. These are MicroTouch's IC-series kiosks. Is it taking resources that get filled when used for a long time and filled? The player used by the dev is Exo Player. Is there any possible way to find out the exact reason why it's happening?
I tried using it for a whole day. Kept it on for 2 days, but I didn't track the issue. We only face this issue at the user site where these kiosks are installed and when continuously used for 3 or 4 days.

Have you considered monitoring logcat for errors? Your high-level description will not get you closer to a solution, you need to analyze the problem when it occurs. Otherwise consider implementing something into the app that makes the app kill itself it it is running for more than 24 hours and the system time shows that it is safe to restart the app and nobody has used the app for an hour.

Cross-posted from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78792611/2821954.
